# Lateral Join returns too many rows

Tags: postgresql, lateral-join

I try to understand `LATERAL JOIN` with this query:

```
select m1.contributor_prescription, derniere_publication.date_publication_prescription 
from activite.metadonnee m1
left join lateral 
(select date_publication_prescription, m2.contributor_prescription 
from activite.metadonnee m2 
where m1.contributor_prescription = m2.contributor_prescription 
order by date_publication_prescription desc
limit 3) as derniere_publication
ON true
order by m1.contributor_prescription
```

The goal is to have for each `contributor_prescription` the 3 latest `date_publication_prescription`.

For now, the result is all `contributor_prescription` rows and the last `date_publication_prescription` for all.

| contributor_prescription | date_publication_prescription |
| --- | --- |
| john | 22/10/2023 |
| john | 22/10/2023 |
| (as many times as john exists in the table) |  |
| paul | 24/10/2023 |
| paul | 24/10/2023 |
| (as many times as paul exists in the table) |  |

**expected:**

| contributor_prescription | date_publication_prescription |
| --- | --- |
| john | 22/10/2023 |
| john | 21/10/2023 |
| john | 20/10/2023 |
| paul | 24/10/2023 |
| paul | 23/10/2023 |
| paul | 21/10/2023 |

Comment: It seems that self join is the issue because it works with two different tables. My question may be inappropriate.

Comment: your code is easier to read for most people here if you stick with english names

Comment: The point of a left join is not include all rows from the left table - I think you want an inner join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the top 3 most recent per `contributor_prescription` you can order them with `row_number()`, then keep only the top 3 using a plain `where`: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/xoQyZILq)

```
with cte as (
    select contributor_prescription, 
           date_publication_prescription,
           row_number()over w1 as rn
    from activite.metadonnee m1
    window w1 as (partition by contributor_prescription
                      order by date_publication_prescription desc) )
select contributor_prescription,
       date_publication_prescription
from cte 
where rn<=3
order by 1,2 desc;
```

| contributor_prescription | date_publication_prescription |
| --- | --- |
| john | 2023-10-22 |
| john | 2023-10-21 |
| john | 2023-10-20 |
| paul | 2023-10-24 |
| paul | 2023-10-23 |
| paul | 2023-10-21 |

Or you *could* do what you did, but don't join straight to the source table, but to `distinct contributor_prescription`:

```sql
select m1.contributor_prescription, 
       derniere_publication.date_publication_prescription 
from (select distinct contributor_prescription from activite.metadonnee) m1
left join lateral 
(   select  date_publication_prescription, 
            m2.contributor_prescription 
    from activite.metadonnee m2 
    where m1.contributor_prescription = m2.contributor_prescription 
    order by date_publication_prescription desc
    limit 3) as derniere_publication
ON true
order by m1.contributor_prescription
```

Otherwise you're asking every single row to show you 3 most recent rows with the same `contributor_prescription`, needlessly multiplying everything. Note the [performance of that isn't great](https://dbfiddle.uk/BypnC7gw).

There's also a very brief method of collecting into an array, taking a slice and unnesting that:

```sql
select contributor_prescription, unnest(arr)
from (select contributor_prescription, 
            (array_agg(date_publication_prescription 
                       order by date_publication_prescription desc))[:3] arr
      from activite.metadonnee
      group by 1) a;
```

But the most performant would be the infamous ([still emulated](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/19/1741/)) [index skip scan](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/NFWl9A_b)

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
   SELECT contributor_prescription,
          1 as rank_pos,
          max(date_publication_prescription) AS date_publication_prescription
   FROM activite.metadonnee 
   GROUP BY contributor_prescription
   UNION ALL
   SELECT contributor_prescription,
          rank_pos+1,
          (SELECT max(date_publication_prescription) 
           FROM activite.metadonnee 
           WHERE date_publication_prescription < t.date_publication_prescription
           AND contributor_prescription=t.contributor_prescription)
   FROM t 
   WHERE rank_pos<3
   )
SELECT contributor_prescription, date_publication_prescription
FROM t;
```

Comment: Thanks for these explanations. Now,I understand why my `lateral join` was not correct. Working with an array is something I didn't think about : nice idea. (For now recursive is beyond my understanding.)

Comment: @Leehan [The feature](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE) is definitely worth a look. In terms of performance, index skip scan is running circles around the other solutions here. It's also great for trees/hierarchies and whatever you'd want a "loop" for. Also, it's actually iterative, so don't get scared off by the keyword.